# "this" not updated inside TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to add an object of type `Error`to an array using a method. So here is my code:

```
export type Error{
    types: string[];
    message: string;
}

export class Form {
    [k: string]: any;
    id: string;
    errors: Error[];

    constructor(obj?: Form) {
      this.id = '';
      if (obj) {
            Object.assign(this, obj);
            if (obj.errors) {
                this.errors = obj.errors.map(x => ({...x}));
            }
      }
    }

    public addError = (error: Error) => {
        this.errors.push(error);
    }
}
```

If I do create a new `Form` and add an `Error` to it, errors array is not updated!!!

```
const form1 = {errors: []};
const form2 = new Form(form1);
form2.addError ({types: ['a'], message: 'error'});
//form2.errors.length returns 0
```

I'm creating a new instance of `Form` because I want to handle deep copy inside my constructor.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `errors` is an empty arr though?

Comment: Sorry @nem035, missed one line

Comment: `adderror` !== `addError`... Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's not the issue it was typo

Comment: You should be seeing several compile-time errors...

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code, which should be showing up as compile-time errors:

- The `type` keyword expects the name following it to be followed by an equals sign. If it were a class, then you could remove the equals.
- If you have a class with methods and want to pass it as a variable, you should either

  - use `new`, or
  - include all defined methods and properties in the object literal you use.
- Or, if all you want is the properties, use an interface, as I've done below.

```js
export type Error = {
    types: string[];
    message: string;
}

export interface IForm {
    [k: string]: any;
    id: string;
    errors: Error[];
}

export class Form implements IForm {
    [k: string]: any;
    id: string;
    errors: Error[];

    constructor(obj?: IForm) {
      this.id = '';
      if (obj) {
            Object.assign(this, obj);
            if (obj.errors) {
                this.errors = obj.errors.map(x => ({...x}));
            }
      }
    }

    public addError = (error: Error) => {
        this.errors.push(error);
    }
}

const form1: IForm = { errors: [], id: 'form1'};
const form2 = new Form(form1);
form2.addError({types: ['a'], message: 'error'});
console.log(form2.errors.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce using the code you provided. In this screen capture you can see that form2.errors is an array with the expected 1 element in it. (the error underline for form1 is pointing out that form1 doesn't have an id property):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your `[k: string]: any;` is damaging the safety net that TypeScript gives you.

If you didn't have it, you would have gotten a compilation error for `adderror` not being a thing, and TypeScript would have even suggested `addError` as the closest valid alternative.